# How do i tell Maven to download all versions of a pom.xml instead of a single version?

Tags: maven, version, pom.xml, snapshot, mvn-repo

I have a master pom.xml with various snapshots and lot of versions. When building the pom.xml , we see only a single version getting downloaded in the m2/localrepo, where as we want to  download all versions of a snapshot. On running mvn clean install, we are getting warnings as "dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique"
 Please check the below xml for the artifactId 'dtc-api-commons' i have a lot of versions which i need to download in my local m2 repository.

```
**XML:**    
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.dtd</groupId>
      <artifactId>dtc-api-commons</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.dtd</groupId>
      <artifactId>dtc-api-commons</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1_1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.dtd</groupId>
      <artifactId>dtc-api-commons</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.dtd</groupId>
      <artifactId>dtc-api-commons</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

**COmmand:**    
mvn clean install
**Expected Output:**      
 3.3.0-SNAPSHOT 3.3.1.SNAPSHOT 3.3.1_1-SNAPSHOT 3.3.2-SNAPSHOT
**Actual Output**        
3.3.2-SNAPSHOT
Error:
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.dtd:dummy-built:jar:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.dtd:dtc-api-commons:jar -> version 3.3.2-SNAPSHOT vs 3.3.1-SNAPSHOT @ line 15, column 13
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.dtd:dtc-api-commons:jar -> version 3.3.2-SNAPSHOT vs 3.3.0-SNAPSHOT @ line 15, column 13
```

Please help in downloading all versions of a artifact using the correct maven command.

Comment: Having the same question as Robert: Why would you like to do this?

Comment: Basically these are our snapshots and not movied as releases, so we need to secure it for future purposes. Basically a kind of backup where sometimes, artifacts can be deleted from Maven Central

Comment: You are mistaken a basic concept for Maven Central. In Maven Central you have only releases which are immutable and will never be deleted (extremely rare exceptions).  Furthermore if you are using SNAPSHOT versions you should change to use releases instead. This means producing releases and store them into a repository managers release repository (and of course backup that) and never rely on SNAPSHOT's if those artifacts are created by yourself. If those artifacts are created by other projects I would suggest to wait to get a release of them via Central...and always use a repository manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because Maven has the concept of dependency resolution where the nearest wins.
Probably the easiest solution is to write a shell/batch script calling [dependency:get](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) for every version.
But maybe I should ask another important question:

```
Why?
```